# Concat dataframes in sequential manner

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe like this:

```
df1:

  start_date  end_date
0 20180101    20181231
1 20170101    20171231
```

Another dataframe like this:

```
df2:

   Type    Value
0  House   100
1  Car     200
2  Bus     300
3  House   150 
4  Car     220  
5  Bus     320
```

I need to concat it in a way that df1's first values (start_date 20180101 and end_date 20181231) is applied to the first round of Types of df2 and the second to the second round and so on (first time "House" appears it should have start_date 20180101 and end_date 20181231; second time "House" appears it should have start_date 20170101 and end_date 20171231 and so on). It should look like this:

df3:

```
   Type    Value  start_date  end_date
1  House   100    20180101    20181231
2  Car     200    20180101    20181231
3  Bus     300    20180101    20181231
4  House   150    20170101    20171231
5  Car     220    20170101    20171231
6  Bus     320    20170101    20171231
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we create `rounds` column in `df2` which indicates the seperate rounds as soon `House` appears again.

Then we create a `rounds` column in `df1` as well for each row.

Finally we `merge` on the `rounds` column:

```
df2['rounds'] = df2['Type'].eq('House').cumsum()
df1['rounds'] = df1.index + 1

df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='rounds', how='left').drop(columns='rounds')
```

**Output**

```
    Type  Value  start_date  end_date
0  House    100    20180101  20181231
1    Car    200    20180101  20181231
2    Bus    300    20180101  20181231
3  House    150    20170101  20171231
4    Car    220    20170101  20171231
5    Bus    320    20170101  20171231
```

---

**Note**:

I assumed your `df1 index` starts at `1`, if it starts at `0`, remove the `+1`

Comment: @Erlan thanks, worked perfectly. However apparently you assumed the index starts at 1. If it starts at 0 I should remove the +1. Right?

Comment: See the last part after `Note`: @abutremutante

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Its apparently inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Let us use `cumcount`

```
df2.assign(index=df2.groupby('Type').cumcount()).\
      merge(df1.reset_index(),on='index').drop('index',1)
Out[59]: 
    Type  Value  start_date  end_date
0  House    100    20180101  20181231
1    Car    200    20180101  20181231
2    Bus    300    20180101  20181231
3  House    150    20170101  20171231
4    Car    220    20170101  20171231
5    Bus    320    20170101  20171231
```